# How to stream RTMPE using Adobe media server and JWplayer

Tags: session, video-streaming, jwplayer, rtmp, adobe-media-server

I have access to a Adobe media server for providing streaming media service for my web clients. I want to use RTMPE streaming to protect my contents from unauthorized access. I RTMPE uses Diffie–Hellman key exchange then I needn't any security certificate. I want just authorized clients be able to access the server programs; then I have to use session key of clients for generating media access keys. I am using jwplayer as player; how can I inject session key for generating RTMPE keys in jwplayer parameters? Also can anyone guide me about RTMPE configurations on Adobe media serve?

Comment: I believe if your have the RTMPE stream, the JW Player should simply be able to play it if the stream is fed in to the player.